# Relational databases - best practice for mapping to multiple entities, with different statuses?

Tags: many-to-many, relational-database

I'm creating a relational database where `User` and `Team` entities have a many-to-many relationship.

When a `User` joins a `Team`, their membership of the group is initially pending, and later goes out of a pending state.

Which of the two following approaches would be the most natural choice in a relational database?

- `Team` objects have a list of  `Member` objects, with the properties `isPending` (a boolean) and `user` (a `User` object).
- `Team` objects have two lists of `User` objects: `members` and `pendingMembers`

I would also like a solution which could potentially scale to hold more fields. For instance, each `Team` may have a `User` who is designated as its leader. Should `Member` have another boolean flag `isLeader`, or should the `Team` object have a field `iseader`, of type `User`?

Answer (score 1):

Full normal form setup would be:

```
User
    userid, PK
    username

UserType
    usertype, PK
    usertypename 

Team
    teamid, PK
    teamname

Status (leader or regular)
    statudid, PK
    statusname

UserInTeam
    teamid, FK, Team.teamid
    userid, FK, User.userid
    usertypeid, FK, UserType.usertypeid
    statusid, FK, Status.statusid
```

---

This method of setting up the UserInTeam table covers all cases.  Ex. a user is a leader in team 1, and a regular user in team 2.  Any combination is possible.

If a user can only be a leader **or** a regular user in all it's assigned teams, you could link the UserType to the User table instead.

Avoid boolean statuses.  Setting it up in a separate table allows you to add new values later, and your queries will still work.